# How to draw UML Class diagram for my following java code?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I have an abstract process class

```
Abstract class **A**
```

it has member function `run()`

classes **B,C,D,E** are inherited from abstract class **A**.

I have an class called **F** (ProcessFactory) which has a function called `getProcess()` which takes argument and gives one instance of specified type of process object.

Now another class called **G** which uses class **F** and get the instances of class **B,C,D,E** and work on them.

I would be happy if someone can provide an UML class diagram for the above scenario. As my classes involves threads, so is there anything which can show in UML for thread related classes?

Comment: Odd question. Is this homework?

Comment: No its not. but I am confused when I am reading a concepts from UML tutorial.

Comment: Could you provide more details on your classes (since you said that you need to draw an UML Class diagram based on some existing code, otherwise we would be imagining your classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UML class diagram is a static diagram, so it doesn't care if a class is a thread, a process or a monkey. Everything is a class, which has attributes and methods. You can state that `A` inherits from thread, but that's about all you can say about threads. So you would get something like this:

[image]

- **Edit**: please see my comment below for clarification.

Comment: I don't think G has a direct relationship with A. It's using F as a sort of proxy to access the classes B, C, D, and E.  From the diagram I would bet that the return type of getProcess() would be of type A even though the specific instance being returned would be one of the child classes. I'm not sure how to represent that in UML.

Comment: I am with Kelly. This was my concern, so put this question. I am confused if I should draw the arrow from F to A or G to A.

Comment: You are right, you would also need a dependency arrow from F to A. I drew a direct relationship from G to A assuming that G calls some function in the instances that he receives from F, that for G sees as instances of A (since this is what F returns). Hope I made myself clear.